# Check if tag contains posts

Tags: php

Hey I am trying to come up with some logic for if a tag contains any posts

I found the below code for a category

```
<?php if (get_category('17')->category_count > 0) { ?>

<?php } ?>
```

I have tried modifying it with `get_tag` in place of `get_category` which did not work. I thought this could be because `category_count` can't be used with the tag taxonomy but I couldn't find any tag equivalent in the codex

Thank you

Comment: You've to be careful not to use the *count* property for the error object or the *null* output of `get_term()`. There are no such checks in your posted code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<?php if (get_tag('17')->count > 0) { ?>

<?php } ?>
```

[`get_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_tag/) is basically a [`get_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/) with taxonomy `post_tag` and `get_term` returns [`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) object on success, `WP_Error` on error.

[`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) has property `$count` which has object count for the term in process.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using the `get_term_field()`:

```
$count = get_term_field( 'count', 17, 'post_tag' );

if( is_int( $count ) && $count > 0 )
{
    // tag contains posts
}
```

where we check if the output is an integer greater than zero.

We could then create a custom wrapper:

```
/**
 * Check if a term has any posts assigned to it
 *
 * @param  int|WP_Term|object $term
 * @param  string             $taxonomy 
 * @return bool 
 */
function wpse_term_has_posts( $term, $taxonomy )
{
    $count = get_term_field( 'count', $term, $taxonomy );
    return is_int( $count ) && $count > 0;  
}
```

Usage example:

```
if( wpse_term_has_posts( 17, 'post_tag' ) )
{
    // do stuff
}
```